# flink on yarn use table api read from hive ,many hive file caused flink used all resource(cpu,memory)

Tags: hive, apache-flink, hadoop-yarn

when I use flink execute one job that read from hive to deal ,hive include about 1000 files,the flink show the parallelism is 1000,flink request resources used  all resources of my cluster that caused others job request slot faild,others job executed faild.each file of 1000 files is small. the job maybe not need occupy the all resources.how can I tune the flink  param that use less resource to execute the job

Answer (score 0):

**Yarn perspective**

I don't recommend usage of Yarn's memory management. Yarn kills containers instantly when they exceed the limits. Usually you need to disable memory checks to overcome this kind of problems.

```json
"yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled":"false",
"yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled":"false"
```

**Flink perspective**

You can't limit slot resource usage. You have to tune your task managers on your needs. By reducing slots or running multiple task managers on each node . You can set task manager resource usage limit by [taskmanager.memory.process.size](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/config/#basic-setup).

Alternatively you can use flink on kubernetes. You can create [Flink clusters for each job](https://www.cncf.io/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/CNCF-Webinar_-Apache-Flink-on-Kubernetes-Operator-1.pdf) which will give you more flexibility. It will create task managers for each job and destroy them when jobs are completed.

There are also [stateful functions](https://flink.apache.org/2021/02/10/native-k8s-with-ha.html) which you can deploy job pipeline operators into separate containers. This will allow you to manage each function resources separately beside task managers. This allows you to reduce pressure on task managers.

Flink also supports [Reactive Mode](https://flink.apache.org/2021/05/06/reactive-mode.html). This also can reduce pressure on workers by scaling up/down operators automatically based on cpu kind of metrics.

You need to discover this kind of features and find best solution for your needs.

Comment: thanks,I had solved the problem . I use table api to read from hive , Table config can set params to limit the hive source parallelism .